ICs that share the same supply voltage
Do I need decoupling caps on each V+ pin of my I/O expanders when they're all sharing the same 5 V supply?

Yes, you do, as close as possible to the V+ and gnd pins.

It depends how far apart they are. And how long wiring you used. There is also no clear threshold how far is far enough or near enough.

I suspected but wanted to be sure. Thank you.

Just to expand on my previous comment- Can you get away without decoupling caps on each part? Sometimes, depending on loading, di/dt, and lots of other factors.  But a decoupling cap is almost free, and putting one on each IC can save you a lot of debug later so it's almost a no-brainer to do it.

“Do I need” the answer is “maybe”.
“Should I add” the answer is almost always “yes”, and close to the supply pins and if there are multiple supply pins, at least one for each.
That’s for the low capacitance / low ESR eg. 100nF ceramic caps. If you have a bulk capacitor (and usually you should) then one may be enough.

Yes, as close to the chip as you can get.  If the chip has multiple VCC pins, then each VCC should be individually bypassed to the closest ground, or if the datasheet gives a bypass scheme, you should follow that.

It is good practice to use them, as close as possible to the device requiring the decoupled signal. This can compensate for potential voltage drop and from interference from circuit traces.
